# Create a bubble speech rectangle using css

Tags: html, css, design-patterns, css-transitions

I want to create a speech bubble kind of structure but with a little customized structure . I tried with some basic border-width technique here . any suggestion will be helpful

[image: The design i want to achieve]

[image: the second image is what i have now :]

Answer (score 0):

You can speech bubbles like drawing shapes and adding them together.
Study those links for more information

[CSS Speech bubbles](https://codingislove.com/css-speech-bubbles/)
[CSS shapes](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/)

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:5px;
}
.triangle:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 10px solid grey;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid grey;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  right: -20px;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box triangle">Type your text here</div>
```